# Is there any Open Office or Libre Office SDK for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, openoffice-impress, odp

I need to extract text from presentation files (.odp) that were created in Libre Office Impress.

I thought this would be super easy (I already implemented this function for .ppt and .pptx files). But I can't find any sample code out there that would let me open up .odp files. :(

Any suggestions on implementing this feature?

Comment: I was actually looking for code, not outside resources. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at: [OASIS Open Document Format for Office Applications (OpenDocument) TC](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=office)

You will find out, that any (Open Document)-document is just a Zip-file which contains Xml-files.

Comment: You actually gave me a good idea. I ended up writing a class that unzipped the .ODP file, deserialized the content.xml file, and extracted all the text from it. Thanks!